# Azure Devops: Creating branch based on another branch suddendly not possible anymore

Tags: git, azure-devops, branch

First of all: we did not change anything regarding permissions or similar.

The part highlighted with that red circle is just missing.
It worked yesterday morning, but didn´t after around 1pm.

I checked the MS tutorials (where I got that pic from) but can´t find a solution.

How to (re-)enable this dropdown menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an issue with the current Work Items hub. Enable the preview feature to fix it:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: suggestions from the dev community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Work-Item-New-Branch--Create-Branch/10350557?q=work+item+create+branch